# How to style a logo as a link?

Tags: html, css

How can I style this into a clickable image link ?

```
    <h1 class="logo">
        <a class="logo__link" href="main.html">
            <img class="logo__img" src="Image/Logo_1.PNG" alt="logo">
        </a>
    </h1>
```

Comment: can you describe your issue?

Comment: The a tag, which is the clickable area is not same as the img size

Comment: Explain your issue properly!

Comment: h1 provides default padding/margins. Set that to 0 or better yet get a CSS reset for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same code you have provided, I added a few css to make the `a` cover the image, as well as setting a width to the `img` so that it will be contained in the `a`.

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.logo__link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="logo">
        <a class="logo__link" href="main.html">
            <img class="logo__img" src="https://www.logo.bot/blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Untitled-3-26-1.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
    </h1>
```